# PHP: Echoing HTML When Multiple Checkboxes Options Are Checked

Tags: php, checkbox

I've edited this question, because I felt I needed to be clearer in my request.

The code below relates to options checked in a checkbox. It will echo 'both values' when they are both checked, and it will echo 'only valueA', I cannot get it to echo 'only valueB' which instead prints blankly with no echo. Thoughts?

```
<?php
 if (( $a == "General" ) && ( $b == "Specialist" )) {
 echo '<h2>both values are printed in HTML</h2>';                                
 }
?>

<?php
 if (( $a == "General" ) && ( $b != "Specialist" )){
 echo '<h2>only valueA is printed in HTML</h2>';                                
 }
?>

<?php
 if (( $a != "General" ) && ( $b == "Specialist" )) {
 echo '<h2>only valueB is printed in HTML</h2>';                                
 }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please post HTML code of the generated form or at least checkbox related snippet?

Comment: For combination of conditions `$CheckBox == $a && $b` is not ok. It has to be something like `if(($CheckBox == $a) && ($CheckBox == $b))`

Comment: The generated code actually only exists in the form of a field data array that a wordpress plugin creates so there's no html that is created automatically. All HTML & PHP needs to be hand written.
   ` [field] => Array
        (
            [1.] => Array
                (
                    [0] => valueA
                    [1] => valueB
                )`

Comment: `if(($CheckBox == $a) && ($CheckBox == $b)) ` doesn't seem to work and is one of the variations I had tried previously.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a value is in array you should use `in_array` function. Your code should look like this:

```
<?php

$CheckBox = $form_data['field'][1]

$a = ( "valueA");
$b = ( "valueB");

$isAChecked = in_array($a, $CheckBox[1]);
$isBChecked = in_array($b, $CheckBox[1]);
?>

<?php
if  ( $isAChecked && $isBChecked ) {
     echo '<h2>both values are printed in HTML</h2>';                                
} else if ( $isAChecked ) {
     echo '<h2>only valueA is printed in HTML</h2>';                                
} else if  ( $isBChecked ) {
     echo '<h2>only valueB is printed in HTML</h2>';                                
} else {
    echo '<h2>nothing printed</h2>'
}
?>
```

Comment: I feel like we are getting off topic. My existing code works and is able to return single checked options, I just need to be able to echo a unique answer if a combination of options are checked.

Comment: As I can see from your code the problem is that you are not deal with `$form_data['field'][1]` as array. Because `$CheckBox == $a && $b` clause should be `in_array($a, $CheckBox[1]) && in_array($b, $CheckBox[1])` as `$CheckBox[1] ` contains array of checked values